# Is there a prime number between every prime and its square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For each prime number $p$, is there always an other prime number between $p$ and $p^2$ ?

I tested it for prime numbers $< 500,000,000$, but I wanted to know if there is any mathematical proof of this ?

Comment: Can anyone give a direct combinatorial proof of this?

Comment: Would $\pi(x) \ge \log x / \log 2$ be enough?

Comment: question is claiming about Prime number between P and $P^2$ so see when we takes P-1 = k < P so there will be possibility that prime number lies between $(P-1)^2$ and $P^2$ according to ***Oppermann's conjecture*** and this inequality  :
    P< $(P-1)^2$ < $P^2$  always holds true

So there will be always prime number between P and $P^2$ .hence proved.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE : Oppermann's conjecture is not proven so if it become false then the above prove will not be considered as answer.

Answer (score 27):

Yes.  By [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) (actually a theorem), for every natural number $n$ (and thus every prime) there is a prime between $n$ and $2n$.  As $p^2 \gt 2p$ for all primes $p$ greater than $2$, there is another prime in this interval, and when $p=2$, $3$ comes between $p$ and $p^2$.

Comment: A much harder, indeed, still wide open question is whether for every $n$ there's a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.

Comment: Yes, but if you put 3 instead 2, the result it's true.

Comment: Is anything known about the number of primes in such intervals? Does it diverge to infinity for instance?

Comment: @Tobias There's approximation of number of primes less than given `x`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_counting_function